# Double quotes in bash

Tags: bash, shell, quoting

I am trying to create a bash file which calls a program that expects a parameter to submitted between two double quotes.

Take a look at my file content.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &
```

The echo part prints exactly the command I need, but when I comes to execute it (next line), I am messing it up.

How can I get this fixed?

Thanks!

This is how I need to call it:

```
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s 9999999999 "my parameter" -c yowsup/config
```

Echo result:

```
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s 9999999999 "my parameter" -c yowsup/config
```

Call result:

```
demos: error: unrecognized arguments: parameter
```

Copying and pasting echo results:

```
INFO:yowsup.demos.sendclient.layer:Message sent
```

Comment: What's in $2? What happens if you just double quote both the variables? `--s "$1" "$2" -c`

Comment: See my comments

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the quotes in the `echo` command to see them in the output, but you shouldn't escape them in the actual command:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config &
```

The quotes are used in the actual command to prevent splitting of `$2` - which contains multiple words.

Comment: @user1688175 by the way, if you do want to see what commands get executed, use `set -x` instead of complicated echo commands.

Answer (score -1):

I (nearly) always quote everything to "echo", so I would do the above like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 \"$2\" -c yowsup/config &"
./yowsup/yowsup-cli demos --s $1 "$2" -c yowsup/config &
```

The difference with @muru solution is, that there the original echo command is run "in the background" - here it's echoing to the screen in the foreground, but run as a background command. (@muru's also doesn't show the ampersand at the end of the command.)

Comment: At first it looked like you just copy-pasted @muru's answer and that might be why you get the downvotes. so I (hopefully) made the "As it stands" text less ambigious.

Comment: Thanks Anthon, your edit looks like a much better explanation. (An "echo" command without quotes always looks dangerous to me.)